# Reading an input file and ignoring blank lines or lines starting with # in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to read through a file that has a few lines of information starting with # and then a list of data. I need to sort through this data and count the lines, find the highest number of a few columns, and print how many of each filetype I find. Along with this I need to avoid blank lines. An example file would be:

```
# Begin 
# File    |      Popularity    |      Uses     |      Name 
asdf.exe       | 4         |         280       |     asdf
firefox.exe   |  1         |         3250       |    firefox.exe
image.png    |   2          |        2761        |   image
start       |    5           |       100          |  start
font.txt   |     6            |      20            | font
smile.txt       |3             |     921            |smile
```

note: | stands for a whitespace of undetermined length

I am having alot of trouble trying to account for the whitespaces between columns and seperating integers and strings inside each line along with accounting for # and blank lines, so I would really appreciate any advice at all since I am stuck. I don't want any actual code but ideas to start.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a whole line. Then use `fscanf()` to match it with each field. Most of `fscanf()` format specifiers conveniently ignore leading white spaces, which is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `fgets` to read lines from the file. You can check the first character of the line for `'#'` or `'\n'` and process it accordingly.

```
// max length of a line in the file
#define MAX_LEN 100

char linebuf[MAX_LEN];

// assuming the max length of name and filename is 20
char filename[20+1]; // +1 for the terminating null byte
char name[20+1];  // +1 for the terminating null byte
int p; // popularity
int u; // uses

FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("error in opening file\n");
    // handle it
}

while(fgets(linebuf, sizeof linebuf, fp) != NULL) {
    if(linebuf[0] == '#' || linebuf[0] == '\n')
        continue;  // skip the rest of the loop and continue

    sscanf(linebuf, "%20s%d%d%20s", filename, &p, &u, name);
    // do stuff with filename, p, u, name 
}
```

Note that the `%d` conversion specifier in the format string reads and discards any number of leading whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used sscanf before so thats what was really confusing me. It all makes sense now

Comment: @ajay: Note: "A whitespace in the format ... sscanf will ... discard ... whitespace characters ..." is true.  But had the format been `"%20s%d%d%20s"` (without) white-space, the results would be the same.  All format specifiers (except %n %[ %c) ignore leading white-space.  The trailing white-space of `"%20s %d %d %20s "` does not affect anything.  +1 for `fgets()` and `%20`

Comment: @chux was in a hurry so didn't notice. Yes, now it's much better. All redundancies removed. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

use this to skip comment lines:

```
while(fscanf(file, "%1[#]%*[^\n]\n") > 0) /**/;
```

then use this to read one line:

```
int ret = fscanf(file, "%s %d %d %s\n" ...)
```

After reading any lines, repeat the comment munger.